# Check if typing in a text box in Python

Tags: python, pyautogui

I was doing a test and I didn't want it to be like this. I want to check if they are using a text box.

Here is my code:

```
import time
import pyautogui
import subprocess as sp

time.sleep(3)

programName = "notepad.exe"
fileName = "Virus.txt"
sp.Popen([programName, fileName])

time.sleep(3)

pyautogui.typewrite("this is a virus try to escape(:", interval=0.1)
```

(This was for a project. I wasn't planning to make a virus I just thought it might be fun.)

When you open Notepad it automatically starts typing in the text box but it could be still opening when it starts and I don't like the `time.sleep` so that is why I need help.

Comment: I don't get your point. You open Notepad, enter some text in there and want to see if someone types something? In notepad? Python does not control Notepad, so the only option is to store the file and see if that changes imho.

Comment: @BlueNerf please give some more information about your problem.

Comment: if you want to do key logging, then `pyautogui.waitKey()`....